# Tuple output when using argrelextrema to array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to obtain the index of the local maxima of an array, `a`. When I use

```py
import numpy as np
argrelextrema(a,np.less)
```

The output is the following tuple:

```
(array([  maxima_1,  maxima_2, maxima_3, ...,maxima_n]),)
```

where `maxima_i` indicates the index of each maxima. I would like to simply convert this into an array with elements:
`maxima_1, maxima_2,...,maxima_n`
I've tried using `np.asarray`, but this leaves me with an array of one element containing all the indexes in one element.

Comment: how did you use `np.asarray`? Give a minimal example

Comment: `np.asarray(argrelextrema(a,np.less))` returns `[[maxima_1 maxima_2 ... maxima_n]]` i.e each element is just seperated by a space and there are two layers of square brackets

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code (3rd printed Value):

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0])
print('Defulat Output{}, Numpy Array Output {}, Array output = {}'.format(argrelextrema(a,np.less), np.asarray(argrelextrema(a,np.less)), list(argrelextrema(a,np.less)[0]) ))
```

Output:

[image]